# Chart doesn't display fonts

Tags: fonts, chart.js

All labels and title on my chart weren't buffered to chart:
[image]

I'm using simple (default) fonts.conf and I'm triggering the chart only by using *renderToBuffer (configuration)* command.
No WARNs or ERRORs in console. Any reason?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in dependencies:
https://github.com/SeanSobey/ChartjsNodeCanvas/issues/5
Lines responsible for font's installation were enough:

```
yum -y search arial
yum -y install liberation-sans-fonts.noarch
```